# Why does Gmail keep popping up a div labeled 'Original Text'?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

In Chrome, every time I click on something like *Select: All*, I get a popup div from Gmail that says

> Original Text: `XXX`

where `XXX` is the list of options to the right of select.

What is this? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot?

Comment: Are you running the Dev version of Chrome by any chance?

Comment: @pelms I have the dev tools installed.

Comment: I meant the development version of Chrome (which thends to be more quirky). You can tell by looking at the version number - current stable version is 5.0.375.99. There's also a beta version which will be a higher version no. than this.

Comment: @pelms no I'm not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try completely closing your browser then reopening your browser and gmail.

Comment: That did it. I still wonder what it was.